# How to migrate from laravel fractal to laravel resource and not repeating my self

Tags: javascript, php, database, laravel

I have been trying to find a way to migrate from laravel fractal to laravel API resource due to its direct usage installing laravel but I'm having an issue migrating functions to API resource. I have functions to filter, sort, get actual responses and cache relating to all my model which avoids me not to repeat myself.

```
trait ApiResponser
{
    private function successResponse($data, $code)
    {
        return response()->json($data, $code);
    }

    protected function errorResponse($message, $code)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => $message, 'code' => $code], $code);
    }

    protected function showAll(Collection $collection, $code = 200)
    {
        if ($collection->isEmpty()) {
            return $this->successResponse(['data' => $collection], $code);
        }

        $transformer = $collection->first()->transformer;

        $collection = $this->filterData($collection, $transformer);
        $collection = $this->sortData($collection, $transformer);
        $collection = $this->paginate($collection);
        $collection = $this->transformData($collection, $transformer);
        $collection = $this->cacheResponse($collection);

        return $this->successResponse($collection, $code);
    }

    protected function showOne(Model $instance, $code = 200)
    {
        $transformer = $instance->transformer;

        $instance = $this->transformData($instance, $transformer);

        return $this->successResponse($instance, $code);
    }

    protected function AuthErrorResponse($message, $code)
    {
        return response()->json(['errors' => ['root' => $message]], $code);
    }

    protected function AuthSuccessResponse(Model $model, $token, $code = 200)
    {
        return response()->json(['data' => $model, 'meta' => ['token' => $token]], $code);
    }

    protected function showMessage($message, $code = 200)
    {
        return $this->successResponse(['data' => $message], $code);
    }

    protected function filterData(Collection $collection, $transformer)
    {
        foreach (request()->query as $query => $value) {
            $attribute = $transformer::originalAttribute($query);

            if(isset($attribute, $value)){
                $collection = $collection->where($attribute, $value);
            }
        }

        return $collection;
    }

    protected function sortData(Collection $collection, $transformer)
    {
        if (request()->has('sort_by')) {
            $attribute = $transformer::originalAttribute(request()->sort_by);

            $collection = $collection->sortBy->{$attribute};
        }
        return $collection;
    }

    protected function paginate(Collection $collection)
    {
        $rules = [
            'per_page' => 'integer|min:2|max:50',
        ];

        Validator::validate(request()->all(), $rules);

        $page = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

        $perPage = 15;

        if (request()->has('per_page')) {
            $perPage = (int) request()->per_page;
        }

        $result = $collection->slice(($page - 1) * $perPage, $perPage)->values();

        $paginated = new LengthAwarePaginator($result, $collection->count(), $perPage, $page, [
            'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
        ]);

        $paginated->appends(request()->all());

        return $paginated;


    }

    protected function transformData($data, $transformer)
    {
        $transformation = fractal($data, new $transformer);
        return $transformation->toArray();  
    }

    protected function cacheResponse($data)
    {
        $url = request()->url();

        $queryParams = request()->query();

        ksort($queryParams);

        $queryString = http_build_query($queryParams);

        $fullUrl = "{$url}?{$queryString}";

        return Cache::remember($fullUrl, 30/60, function() use($data){
            return $data;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say 'repeat myself' I thought you meant how to avoid duplicate code, but I see none in your sample. Can you explain further where you are stuck?

Comment: @JorisJ1 thanks for reaching out. when i try to use laravel API resource i notice the steps to reproduce my api responses seems to be a long process. I want to be able to apply the code functions shown above (which is currently in Laravel Fractal) to the Laravel API resource.  
 which includes sorting, filter and caching.